# How to prompt for input while doing preseed/late_command?

Tags: installation, pxe, preseed

My preseed server install file executes a number of additional tasks with a bash script called with preseed/late_command.   I wish to prompt for a password during this process to install LDAP properly.  How can I do this in debconf style?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Ubuntu Wiki Custom Install CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)

> Generally, a script run from the seed file via late_command, cannot interact with the user. If you need to interact, there are generally three options:

```
1. Create a custom UDEB that interacts with debconf, and include it with the CD.
2. Create a 'firstrun' script that executes the first time the system boots, and disables itself on completion.
3. Access debconf directly within your script.
```

Personally I use the 'first run' method and run the scripts post install. I have not used the other two methods.